# Yaml missed comma flow between collection entries (line starting with square brackets)

Tags: powershell, yaml

I need to include the following powershell script in my .yml file:

```
 [byte[]] $projectFile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($ProjectFilePath)
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: Depends what the error is. Could you add a "complete" yaml example?

Answer (score 3):

`[` is a special character in YAML and starts a flow sequence. If you want that character at the beginning of a scalar, value, quote the value:

```yaml
"[byte[]] $projectFile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($ProjectFilePath)"
```

Alternatively, use a literal block scalar:

```yaml
key: |-
  [byte[]] $projectFile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($ProjectFilePath)
```